# set line border properties (color/width) in a Highcharts line chart

Tags: highcharts, colors, border

Example [code](https://jsfiddle.net/hyer67Lv/):

```
   Highcharts.chart('container', {
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        plotOptions: {
        series: {
            lineWidth: 8,
            color: '#FF0000'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

How can I set color and width for the border of the line?
I need the line appearing like this one:

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.color, https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.lineWidth.

Comment: Already done. I asked for color and with for the border.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve line series with a border by adding additional series with the same data array that is linked to the main one. Then just set greater `lineWidth` and different color.

**Code:**

```
const data = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  series: [{
    lineWidth: 5,
    color: '#000',
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    data: data,
    linkedTo: 'main'
  }, {
    lineWidth: 2,
    id: 'main',
    color: '#FF0000',
    name: 'Test',
    marker: {
        enabled: false
    },
    states: {
        hover: {
        lineWidthPlus: 0
      }
    },
    data: data
  }]
});
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d1m4feyx/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo